# Error creating One-to-One relationships in Entity Framework 6 Code First

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, one-to-one

I am following this tutorial to make a one-to-one relationship but with no avail. 
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

here is my quick mock up

```
public class Information
{
    public int InformationId { get; set; }

    public string Thing1 {get; set;}
    public string Thing2 { get; set;}

    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Information")]
    public int InformationId { get; set; }

    public string Thing1 { get; set; }

    public Information Information { get; set; }
}
```

and I execute this against it

```
var information = new List<Information>{
            new Information(){
                Thing1 = "this",Thing2="that"
            }
        };
        information.ForEach(s => context.Information.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var account = new List<Account>{
            new Account(){Thing1="one"}
        };
        account.ForEach(s => context.Accounts.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

it errors with this

```
{"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.Account_dbo.Information_InformationId\". The conflict occurred in database \"TestEF\", table \"dbo.Information\", column 'InformationId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

Comment: save account first, then information

Comment: thanks, that prevents error, however it seems only 'information' arrives in the database

Comment: when saving account first, then information the error was not thrown. however when looking at the database tables, there was a new record for 'information' but no record for 'account'

Comment: Thanks! After getting no error doing it the way you suggested, I realized the problem was only with how I was saving the entities, not with the association. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save account first, then information

```
var account = new List<Account>{
            new Account(){Thing1="one"}
        };
        account.ForEach(s => context.Accounts.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();

var information = new List<Information>{
            new Information(){
                Thing1 = "this",Thing2="that"
            }
        };
        information.ForEach(s => context.Information.Add(s));
        context.SaveChanges();
```